# Is there a good thread safe Format caching library?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to do some formatting in my webapp, using MessageFormat, DateFormat, DecimalFormat, etc.

Since these are not thread-safe, one static instance for each usage won't work, but it seems wasteful to create a new XXXXFormat object each time one is needed. Caching and re-using them with a ThreadLocal seems like an obvious optimization.

This seems like a very common pattern, so I'm wondering if there are any appropriate libraries.

Instead of calling:

```
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

    String formatted = formatter.format(value);
```

every time I need to format something, why not:

```
    String formatted = FormatCache.formatDecimal("###,##0.00",numberValue);
```

where FormatCache would do the ThreadLocal caching with a HashMap keyed on the format pattern?

Presumably there'd be other methods like:

```
    String FormatCache.formatDecimal(String, Number);
    String FormatCache.formatDate(String, Date);
    String FormatCache.formatMessage(String, Object...);
```

Comment: Sounds like you could write one if you can't find one. ;)

Comment: What research have you done? stackoverflow is not a recomendation engine/google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

Cache a **thread-safe `DateTimeFormatter`** object (immutable).

**Never use `SimpleDateFormat`.** Use only *java.time* package for date-time work.

## java.time

The troublesome old date-time classes such as `DateFormat` & `SimpleDateFormat` are now supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Specifically here, the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

### Immutable objects, thread-safe

The *java.time* classes were designed to be [Immutable Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). This means that rather than modifying any content in the object, a new distinct object is generated. The original is left intact.

This, and other techniques, make the *java.time* classes [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) by design and are so documented.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatterFullQuébec = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
```

You can cache that object `dateTimeFormatterFullQuébec`, keep it around.

### `ZoneId`

Likewise, you could keep a `ZoneId` time zone object cached.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zoneMontréal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Then use them any time, even across threads.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneMontréal ) ;
String output = zdt.format( dateTimeFormatterFullQuébec ) ;
```

> dimanche 4 mars 2018 à 18:36:32 Eastern Standard Time

The *java.time* objects such as `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant` are also immutable and thread-safe, just like the `ZoneId` & `DateTimeFormatter`. You can cache all of these, and use them across threads.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

[Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/lang/) has [`FastDateFormat`](https://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html), which solves the problem the right way (in my opinion), by just being threadsafe to begin with:

> FastDateFormat is a fast and thread-safe version of SimpleDateFormat.
>
> This class can be used as a direct replacement to SimpleDateFormat in most formatting situations. This class is especially useful in multi-threaded server environments. SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe in any JDK version, nor will it be as Sun have closed the bug/RFE.

Comment: Definitely addresses the threading and caching part, but doesn't look like it will handle the non date formats.

Answer (score 2):

You should be really careful with something like that. The standard (simple) formaters are not threadsafe. I've ran into some multithread related issues with some shared/cached formaters, but that was some years ago (Java 1.4). If you check the JavaDocs ([SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)), you will notice the following:

> Synchronization
>
> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

Comment: right - I was suggesting ThreadLocal for just this reason, but didn't explain the rationale. I've edited original post to clarify that this isn't the real question.